# What does get read from an nonexistent XML tag read by Action Script 3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

As the title says, suppose I have an hypothetical XML containing this:

```
<dialogue>
    <bg>1</bg>
    <speech>Oh, what a nice bg1.</speech>
</dialogue>
<dialogue>
    <playsnd>lala.wav</playsnd>
    <speech>Still same bg, but now a sound is played!.</speech>
</dialogue>
```

I'm reading it with a for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<loop; i++)
{
    speeches[i] = xmlData.script.dialogue[i].speech;
    bgs[i] = Number(xmlData.script.dialogue[i].bg);
    sounds[i] = xmlData.script.dialogue[i].playsnd;
}
```

I can check if a certain speech has a bg change by simply doing this:

```
if(bgs[i])
{
//true!
}
```

But I don't have any idea of what should I compare in the case of sounds, I've tried many, like:

```
if(sounds[i])
if(sounds[i] != null)
if(sounds[i] != "")
if(sounds[i] != " ")
```

But nothing works... so what does sounds[0] would contain on the XML example? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlData.script.dialogue[i].playsnd` will give you a value of type `XMLList`, which is a list of all the `<playsnd>` elements. You want to check if that list is empty (i.e. contains zero elements), so:

```
if(sounds[i].length() != 0)
    // do whatever
```

**Edit:** If you're only ever going to have one `<playsnd>` element, then it might make more sense to grab the first item from the `XMLList` in your loop:

```
for(...)
{
    ...
    sounds[i] = xmlData.script.dialogue[i].playsnd[0];
}
```

Then you can check for null and it will work the way you expect:

```
if(sounds[i] != null)
    // do whatever
```

Comment: It works, and the explanation is the thing I was looking for in the first place, thank you very much!

Comment: Going on with this, if(bgs[i]) works because nothing gets stored when converted to a Number, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should check for undefined.

Comment: If there are no `<playsnd>` elements, `xmlData.script.dialogue[i].playsnd` will not return undefined. It will return an empty XMLList. See my answer.

Comment: Also works, but Aaron was faster and more explanatory, anyway, thanks a lot!
Edit: @Aaron: it worked, though xD

Comment: No problem, didn't reply to get an answer heh.